# How many connections are made by producer and consumer to a Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Can anyone shed some light on the number of connections and what type of connections are made by the Kafka Java producers and Kafka Java consumers to a Kafka cluster.

Are the number of connections based on the number of topics or partitions or brokers in the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Each consumer/producer needs to be connected to the broker which is leader for the partition that the consumer/producer wants to read/write.
It means that a client doesn't need to be connected to all brokers inside a cluster but just the brokers needed for reading/sending messages.
During the initial configuration, we provide a list of brokers to connect to (which could be even only one). Using such broker(s), the client gets metadata information about the topic/partitions it wants to use and where they are placed (other brokers in the cluster). Such connections need to be in place for client working on the desired topic/partitions.

Comment: when a connection is made for initial configuration producer/consumer to one of brokers in brokers-list will that connection remain alive until we close producer/consumer? When a message is read/written for the leader of a partition will the connection gets closed immediately once read/written from the client or will it remain until the producer/consumer is closed? Will consumer/producer make multiple connection for one broker which is leader for multiple partitions?

Comment: the general answer is no. From a consumer point of view, it's right because even if the consumer doesn't connect to the broker where the topic leave, that broker will contain partitions of the __consumer_offsets topic (default 50 partitions) used by consumer for committing offset. From a producer point of view, if the producer connects to the "wrong" broker because the topic is on another one, maybe the connection could be closed but it's not.

Comment: can u explain more clearly on the connection made by producer/consumer for initial configuration.

Comment: you know that having a cluster with N brokers and some topics with M partitions, such partitions are distributed (and replicated) on the brokers. When a client wants to read/write to a topic partition it needs to connect to the broker which is the "leader" for that partition (which is replicated on other brokers named "followers"). On start, a client may not know what is the broker where its interested topic partition is. Connecting to just one of the N broker, the client asks for metadata about that topic and knows where it is (the broker to connect to).

Comment: Is it that connections will not get closed in case of consumer during initial configuration ? Will consumer/producer make multiple connection for one broker which is leader for multiple partitions?

Comment: As I said consumer connection won't be closed because it's pretty sure that on the broker will be partitions of the consumer offset topic. Regarding the other question : no, there is only one connection even if the broker is leader for multiple topic partitions.